# Externally powered ESP32 DevKit V1 stops executing after unplugging USB cable

Tags: usb, esp32, wifi

The program below executes perfectly as long as the USB cable is connected.

I have a Blynk device with a couple of sliders and an LED. I'm learning to work with the `BLYNK.WRITE()` function for a much more complex project.

However, neither this code or the larger project will continue executing after I unplug the USB cable.

The project is externally powered by +5 V and 3.3 V.

I have tried everything I can think of, and I can not figure out why the WiFi and program execution stops.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>

#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "xxxx"
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME "xxxx"
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN "xxxx"
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#define RAINING 2

int rainLed = 0;
int tempset = 50;
int humidset = 55;
int tempValue;
int humidValue;
int currentTemp = 50;
int currentHumid = 50;

char auth[] = BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN;
// char ssid[] = "NETGEAR44-pro"; // type your wifi name
char ssid[] = "NETGEAR44"; // type your wifi name
char pass[] = "xxxx"; // type your wifi password

// This function creates the timer object. It's part of Blynk library 
BlynkTimer timer
void myTimer() {
  // This function describes what will happen with each timer tick
  // e.g. writing sensor value to datastream V5
  
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V2, tempset);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, humidset);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V6, rainLed);
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V0) {   
  tempValue = param.asInt(); // Get value as integer
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V1) {   
  humidValue = param.asInt(); // Get value as integer
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(RAINING, OUTPUT); // onboard Led
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  Serial.println(F("Connected to Host!"));
  timer.setInterval(500L, myTimer);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  Blynk.run();
  timer.run();

  rainLed = digitalRead(RAINING);

  if (tempValue >= tempset) {
    digitalWrite(RAINING, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(RAINING, LOW);
  }

  if (humidValue >= humidset) {
    digitalWrite(RAINING, HIGH);
  } else if (tempValue < tempset) {
    digitalWrite(RAINING, LOW);
  }

  Serial.print("Temp Slider Value = ");
  Serial.println(tempValue);
  Serial.print("Rain LED = ");
  Serial.println(rainLed);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Humidity Slider Value = ");
  Serial.println(humidValue);
  Serial.println("");

  delay(300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are powering it via the 5V pin, which can, in fact, take between 5-12 V, then you actually need to supply 7-8 V so that the on-board 5 V voltage regulator works correctly. Anything less than 7 V can mean that the voltage drop across the regulator will prevent the board from receiving the necessary 5 V.

If you are powering via the 3V pin, then this needs to be a *regulated* 3 V, as there is not an on-board 3V3 regulator.

Also, via the USB port, the current supplied is probably 500 mA. Ensure that the supplies that you are connecting to the 5V or 3V pins can supply sufficient current - a 1000 mA supply might to advisable, especially if you have other peripherals (such as sensors) connected.

> The project is Externally powered +5 and 3.3V.

Finally, you only need to supply power to *either* the 5V pin or the 3V pin, but **not** *both* at the same time.

Comment: I will check for Voltage Drop. Ty.